# "ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (3, 4) instead." While using fit() from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I type:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
label_list = np.array([1,2,3])
label_list = label_list.reshape(-1,1)
feature_matrix = np.array([[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1]])
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(label_list,feature_matrix)
```

Then my console output:

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (3, 4) instead.
```

How can I fix it? I am a beginner. Please tell me clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample code, I understand that `label_list` is the "target vector" (the `y`) and `feature_matrix` is the `X` matrix.

So, the correct usage should be:

```
 model.fit(feature_matrix, label_list)
```

Also, you cannot reshape `label_list`:

```
label_list = label_list.reshape(-1,1)
```

because `model.fit()` expects a vector with shape `(n_samples,)` and your are giving a vector with shape `(n_samples, 1)`.

In summary, your code should look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
label_list = np.array([1,2,3])
feature_matrix = np.array([[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1]])
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(feature_matrix, label_list)
```

Comment: That is very kind of you!